# Format doesn't show

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, zero-padding

So I'm trying to get my month numbers to be zero padded from the left meaning {01, 02, 03, ..., 10, 11, 12}.

I thought to do so with formatting but after searching the internet I wonder if formatting really adds a zero or if I'll only see a zero when printed.
Either way, what I was trying:

```
months.style.format({'Test': '{:0>2}'})
print(months)
```

When I use this code it prints the 'Test' column without the format, why is this? I use Jupyter notebook and when I don't use the print function, he displays the data with the right format. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code just changes the format in your jupyter notebook. It's similar to how formatting works in Excel. You can change the format in Excel, but it won't change the value of the cell.

To change the format of your cell do: `df.months = '0' + df.months` where `df` is your dataframe.

EDIT (per comment about October, November and December):

```
import numpy as np
df.months = np.where((df.months < 10), '0' + df.months, '' + df.months)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want a zero in front of october, november and december

Comment: Thank you! I had to add astype(str) and I removed the '' + in the last part and now it works great!

Final code:

months['Test']=np.where((months['Test']<10), '0' + months['Test'].apply(str), months['Test'].apply(str))